# Adding attachment to SOAP UI as inline files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-axis, soapui, soap-client

What are the options need to be enabled in service client to add attachment as inline files. (I dont want to send attachment as MTOM or SWA) just inline files.

Eg: to enable MTOM, we need to set enableMTOM=true like that.

Basic configurations to send attachment as inline files. If possible please share if you have working example for the same

I am using JAVA + AXIS 2. I am trying to send attachment to server

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "inline files".

Comment: Do you mean Base64 encoded content?

Comment: http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html ... Please refer this for inline files

Comment: we can send attachment as MTOM, SWA (SOAP WITH ATTACHMENTS), Anonymous aatchments and as Inline files

Comment: I have encoded my file BASE64. Created DataHandler out of it and trying to send it. I am trying to send as Inline Files as mentioned in doc.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that. I just right-click within the SOAP Body and click on "Insert file as Base64". The file will be Base64 encoded by SoapUI.

Comment: The doc says: "Inline files for binary content - soapUI specific functionality for simplifying handling of binary message content". I guess this means that SOAPUI encodes the content of the file using Base64 and inserts it into the XML, but somebody would have to confirm that since the notion of "inline file" is really specific to SOAPUI and used nowhere else.

Comment: @user2526641, please see if this helps - http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html